# express-session - is it possible to change the secret while the node app is running?

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

Usually the [secret](https://github.com/expressjs/session#secret) is hard-coded in node apps which use [express-session](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis), for example -

```
const session = require("express-session")
let RedisStore = require("connect-redis")(session)
const { createClient } = require("redis")
let redisClient = createClient({ legacyMode: true })
redisClient.connect().catch(console.error)
app.use(
  session({
    store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: "keyboard cat",
    resave: false,
  })
)
```

Obviously I can change this secret `keyboard cat` by editing the source and [restarting](https://nodejs.dev/learn/run-nodejs-scripts-from-the-command-line) the node script. It is possible to change it while the app is still running?

Comment: How often are you trying to change the secret and what is your motivation for changing it?  Separately, how often do you normally restart your server for maintenance or to clean memory and give it a fresh start?

Comment: @jfriend00 My motivation is that I put most of my code on github and I prefer not to hard-code any passwords or secrets. I created an HTML form to allow administrators to `POST` the secret but I think this approach failed because the middleware including the session is already loaded but the time the server receives the secret (via the router `app.post('/login', (req, res) => { ...`)

Comment: Usually, you make the secret part of some configuration/deployment file that is NOT checked into github.  This is the same type of config file you would put database passwords and other credentials needed for your server.  That way, when your server starts up, it gets the credentials/secrets it needs from a local configuration file that is not stored in github.

Comment: @jfriend00 that was my first approach but the filesystem of my Heroku development server is [ephemeral](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted) so my config file is frequently lost.

Comment: See what I added to the end of my answer below now that you mention Heroku.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the guidelines [here](https://github.com/expressjs/session#secret), the session secret can be changed by passing an array of secrets instead of the single secret and you can then `secrets.unshift(newSecret)` a new secret into the first spot in the array while continuing to accept cookies that have used the other secrets in the array.

So, in your code, you would do this:

```
const session = require("express-session");

let RedisStore = require("connect-redis")(session);
const { createClient } = require("redis");
let redisClient = createClient({ legacyMode: true });
redisClient.connect().catch(console.error);

const secrets = ["keyboard cat"];

app.use(
  session({
    store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: secrets,
    resave: false,
  })
);
```

Then, sometime later in your code, you can update the current secret being used like this:

```
secrets.unshift("my new secret");
```

The session middleware will always use the secret at the start of the array for new sessions, but will continue to accept cookies that use the other secrets in the array.

> My motivation is that I put most of my code on github and I prefer not to hard-code any passwords or secrets.

If this is your motivation, then usually, you make the session secret part of some configuration/deployment file that is NOT checked into github and is managed separately.  This is the same type of config file you would put database passwords and other credentials needed for your server.  That way, when your server starts up, it gets the credentials/secrets it needs from a local configuration file that is not stored in github.

Then, you also don't have to try to change a running session middleware secret on the fly either.

---

Now that you mention Heroku, here are the techniques that Heroku mentions for managing configuration variables:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: AFAIK there is a documented way to change the secret without restarting: https://github.com/expressjs/session#secret
e.g. use an array of secrets and shove a new secret up the array as first element from time to time. Is that what the OP is asking for?

Comment: @LucioCrusca - I updated my answer based on that info.